# Problem sending cookie "connect.sid" with browser

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, passport.js

I have an ecommerce created with react (front), meanwhile the back is made with express. My session is handled by passport js, and the problem is that I establish the login or the register without any problem, but when I have to re-check the session, the browser (Chrome) never sends back the cookie, so the server is not able to recognize the session. I checked with postman and it works fine. Does someone know why the front does not send the cookie ("connect.sid")???

I leave here the code of the component in react and the code of my router.

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import ItemList from "./ItemList"
import { myContext } from "../contexto/contexto"
import { useHistory } from "react-router"

const ItemListContainer = () => {
  const contexto = useContext(myContext)
  const history = useHistory()
  const obj = {
    email: sessionStorage.getItem("user")
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios/check-session`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(obj)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json)
      //if (json.session == false) history.push("/")
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },[obj])

  return (
    <ItemList items={contexto.productos} />
  )
}

export default ItemListContainer
```

Here is my server:

```
const { Router } = require("express")
const router = Router()
const upload = require("../../utils/middlewares/multer")
let UsuariosController = require("./controller/usuariosController")
const textUsuarioYaRegistrado = "Email ya registrado!"
const textUsuarioInexistente = "Datos incorrectos!"
    
module.exports = (app,passport) => {
  app.use("/api/usuarios", router)
    
  let isLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next()
      } else {
        res.json({session: false})
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
    
  let isNotLogin = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next()
      } else {
        res.redirect(`${config.FRONT_URI}/productos`)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
        
  //router.post("/nuevo", UsuariosController.createUsuario)
    
  router.post("/guardar-foto", upload.single("foto"), UsuariosController.guardarFoto)
    
  //router.post("/", UsuariosController.getUsuario)
    
  router.post("/nuevo",  passport.authenticate('register', {failureRedirect:`/api/usuarios/error/${textUsuarioYaRegistrado}`}), (req,res,next) => {
    res.json(req.body)
  });
    
  router.post("/", passport.authenticate('login', {failureRedirect:`/api/usuarios/error/${textUsuarioInexistente}`}), (req,res,next) => {       
    res.json(req.user)
  });

  router.get("/error/:errorMessage", (req,res,next) => {
    res.render("error", {error: req.params.errorMessage})
  })
    
  router.post("/check-session", isLogin, UsuariosController.getByEmail)
```

Comment: The browser probably considers the session cookie third-party, because frontend and backend are on different top-level domains (`.frontend.com` vs. `.backend.com`).

Comment: Probably, but I cannot solve the problem. I tried with different configurations of CORS and nothing.

Comment: Third-party cookies has got nothing to do with CORS. A solution would be to [proxy backend requests](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=proxy+to+backend) through your frontend server.

Comment: Forget it, I've done that and nothing. I'm almost sure that the problem is that the front is not sending the connect.sid cookie. There are lots of threads in other pages about this and no one seems to have found a solution....

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is that the front never sends back the cookie. I try all I know, including seting the back cookies "httpOnly: false", nothing.